# My class selector is not displayed in rules in Firefox

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have an animation with an iframe which is reduced and let appear my `.project` container but it looks like my red background for this class is not computed when I use Firefox or Chrome.

[image]

Codepen: http://codepen.io/kejoff/pen/bqmQXQ

***HTML***

```html
<body>
    <a href="#" class="button">Click to resize</a>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="project">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d338195.2873427642!2d2.2500731!3d48.530343949999995!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sfr!4v1490778528424" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen class="map"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

***CSS***

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  width: 6%;
  background-color: #FFC72C;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #071D49;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #071D49;
  color: #FFC72C;
}

.container {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.project {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
  display: block;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.mapAnimationIn {
  animation: resize-gmap 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: block;
}


/* Keyframe resize Gmap */

@keyframes resize-gmap {
  from {
    height: 90vh;
    width: 100%;
  }
  to {
    height: 18vh;
    width: 10vw;
    transform: translate(0, 72vh);
  }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Please provide details about what is *actually* wrong. It's hard for others to guess what is wrong and what you want to have.

Comment: I added more details to my question. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your .container class is getting applied. The problem is that your .project class container completely covers the parent container i.e. .container. Add padding to .container class or reduce width of .map class to below 100%, to see it work. You can do it like so -

```
.container {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 20px;
}

.project {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
.map {
  width: 90%;
 }
```

Also its generally a bad idea to hard code height. To make your page responsive, prefer dynamic width i.e. in % for example rather than in pixels. 
Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks it's working great. It looks like the padding is doing the work :)